# Visual Studio Code showing Python 3.8.5. instead of an actual version (MacOs)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am quite new to programming. Unlike any other issue I've had so far, this one I don't seem to be able to find an answer for anywhere on the web.

My VScode is displaying its current interpreter as python 3.8.5. The actual version is 3.9.5 and I cannot find out why is it so.

Now, I upgraded my python version from 3.8.5 to 3.9.5 via terminal weeks ago, however, packages installed into global enviroment would't import till the moment I actually manually installed the newest 3.9 version and deleted 3.8 from app folder. After that, I am able to call my packages, however, my VSCode still displays the old version and does not offer me 3.9 interpreter.

There must be something I'm missing.

Thanks for reading.